# mutate_at only vars which satisfy a certain condition

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have the following data frame:

```
db <- structure(list(x = c(0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 5, 8), y = c(0, 0, 3, 
4, 8, 9, 1, 5), z = c(3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 6, 9, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a column with the mean of all the other columns **which are greater than 0** (a different set each time.

I have tried the following:

```
db %>% mutate_at(vars(.)>0, rowMeans(.))
```

What am I doing wrong?

The output in the last column should be 3, 1.5, 2.5, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any good option with `dplyr`, except using this trick that replace all negative or zero value with NA, which are excluded from the mean calculation:

```
db %>% 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(.>0,.,NA_integer_)) %>%
  mutate(
    positivemean = rowMeans(., na.rm=TRUE)
  )
```

Note that this trick is destructive as you lose the values of those values.

Without `dplyr` though, you can use an `apply` loop on lines to get the expected output:

```
db$positivemean = db %>% select(x,y,z) %>% apply(1, function(line){
  mean(line[line>0])
})
```